# cert-manager kubernetes service account does not exist or Permission 'iam.serviceAccount.setIamPolicy' denied

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

Trying to follow [cert-manager link kubernetes service account to GCP service account](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/google/#link-ksa-to-gsa-in-gcp) I need to run this command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  --member "serviceAccount:$PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[cert-manager/cert-manager]" \
    dns01-solver@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID
```

but keep getting error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.add-iam-policy-binding) PERMISSION_DENIED: 
 Permission 'iam.serviceAccount.setIamPolicy' denied on 
resource (or it may not exist).
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: iam.googleapis.com
  metadata:
    permission: iam.serviceAccount.setIamPolicy
  reason: IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED
```

I have attached these permissions to the GCP service account (`dns01-solver@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`):

```
DNS Administrator
Project IAM Admin
Service Account Token Creator
Service Account User
Workload Identity User
```

But I keep getting same error which.

Also the Kubernetes service account cert-manager does exist in namespace cert-manager as can be seen here:

[image]

This is it's describe output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add `roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin` to my personal account which triggers the gcloud commands as specified here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity